# Can a question be too basic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I am wondering this in light of [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/82847/when-not-to-use-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99) question.

I don't even think it is a duplicate, but, and I hope I am not rude here, it is such a basic question, that I wonder why one would ask it here. Simply looking for "です" pretty much anywhere would answer the question. And any reasonable Japanese learning resource likely would cover it among the absolute basics.

On the other hand, I can appreciate that as a beginner, there is no way to distinguish between common and complicated parts of the language and not everyone learns using a textbook.

And in general, I wouldn't want to make someone feel unwelcome for asking a "too simple" question.

Answer (score 1):

So I looked up "です meaning" on google and the top result was [this link](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/desu-meaning/). In my opinion this explanation is pretty useless. I think the fact that です has two quite different uses can be confusing to beginners and isn't often well explained.
So in this particular case I think the question was reasonable.

More generally, there certainly is such a thing as a question that is too basic. And when we get those we tend to close them with the "Questions asking for translations, transcriptions or proofreading are off-topic unless prior research effort is clearly indicated" option.

To try and avoid being unwelcoming I normally add a comment explaining what I think the OP should do to improve their question. If there is no response then I cast my close vote. But that's just me. I think casting a close vote with no comment is fine as well. After all, the OP should have read the rules of the site first.